# Terraform adding network endpoints on a Hybrid NEG problem

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

Initially I used to add an network endpoint

```
resource "google_compute_network_endpoint" "endpoint1" {
  network_endpoint_group = google_compute_network_endpoint_group.neggroup.name
  port                   = google_compute_network_endpoint_group.neggroup.default_port
  zone                   = local.primary_zone
  ip_address = "10.10.10.1"
}

resource "google_compute_network_endpoints" "endpoint2" {
  network_endpoint_group = google_compute_network_endpoint_group.neggroup.name
  zone                   = local.primary_zone
  network_endpoints {
    port       = "7301"
    ip_address = "10.10.10.1"
  }
}
```

Additional info:
Note: network_endpoint_type = "NON_GCP_PRIVATE_IP_PORT" on network endpoint group
default port = 7300

-- I removed the resource "google_compute_network_endpoints"

Problem:
Why doesn't terraform plan removing both end points? is that normal? or the way im adding the end point is wrong.

Terraform will perform the following actions:

## google_compute_network_endpoints.endpoint2 will be destroyed

## (because google_compute_network_endpoints.endpoint2 is not in configuration)

```
  - resource "google_compute_network_endpoints" "endpoint2" {
      - id                     = "xxxx/us-east1-b/yyyy/endpoints" -> null
      - network_endpoint_group = "zzzzz" -> null
      - project                = "aaaaa" -> null
      - zone                   = "us-east1-b" -> null

      - network_endpoints {
          - ip_address = "10.10.10.1" -> null
          - port       = 7300 -> null
        }
      - network_endpoints {
          - ip_address = "10.10.10.1" -> null
          - port       = 7301 -> null
        }
    }
```

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

[terraform-provider-gcp](/questions/tagged/terraform-provider-gcp)

I'm expecting that after removing "google_compute_network_endpoint**s**" i can still see the endpoint created by "google_compute_network_endpoint"

Comment: nevermind.. i found the solution..  but still endpoint and endpoints are confusing,,

Comment: Post the solution. Otherwise, delete the post if you no longer need help so that the question is not left open and unsolved forever.